# How can I change the priority for MapService Process?

Tags: arcgis-server

I've got an asynch GP service that exports mxds to pdfs.  Typically the mxd contains mapservice layers.  The same MapServices are also used by interactive clients where draw speed is important.  Drawspeed is not that important for the GP service though.

When the GP service does an export there is a noticeable spike in CPU usage on the machine hosting the MapServices.

I would like to reduce the impact on the CPU posed by this GP service which is hosted on a different machine.

To do that I'm considering creating some new MapServices specifically for use by the GP service.  I'd like for them to serve the same mxd/msd's but run at a lower priority.

Is there a way to configure this?

If not, would setting [Process.PriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx) to BelowNormal with a Server Object Extension (SOE) when IServerObjectExtension.Init gets called have any ill side effects?

Comment: Setting Process.PriorityClass to BelowNormal with a Server Object Extension (SOE) when IServerObjectExtension.Init will work. But if have a dual/quad core you can set one core to do the export leaving the other cores un-effected.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, This is on a virtual machine on Windows 2008, would that still be possible?